# How to remove the special characters for volumne label in zip file passed as Httpresponse in python code

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

How to remove the special characters (PKc¦ÙLx!Ül@) for volumne label (C:)in  zip file passed as Httpresponse, in python? I want to get C: instead of the escape characters. Path should be C:/data/users/admin/testing/profile/p1.tp

```
PKc¦ÙLx!Ül@data/users/admin/testing/profile/p1.tp{
  "name": "p1",
  "description": "p1",
  "package": [
    [
      "S1",
      "s1"
    ]
  ],
  "filename": "p1.tp"
}PKÁµðLá¼Ù<data/users/admin/testing/packages/s1.st{
  "name": "S1",
  "description": "s1",
  "tests": [
    [
      "t1",
      "t1.ts"
    ]
  ],
  "filename": "s1.st"
}
```

i am creating the HttpRespone like this:

```
f = open(zip_file_path, "rb")
response = HttpResponse(f, content_type = 'application/x-zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + zip_filename
return response
```

Comment: try `content_type = 'application/octet-stream'`

Comment: @Joel tried, but same issue